# How to handle Redis connection across multiple modules?

Tags: python, redis

I'm building an application that uses Redis as a datastore. Accordingly, I have many functions that interact with Redis, usually as wrappers for a group of Redis commands.

As the application grows past my initial .py file, I'm at a loss for how to handle the Redis connection across multiple modules. Currently, my pointer to the Redis connection is declared at the top of the file and every function assumes it's present rather than passing it to every function. If I spread these functions into multiple files, then each module creates its own Redis pointer to use and each instance of the application opens up multiple connections to Redis.

I would like one instance to just make use of the same connection.

I **don't** want to do this:

```
import redis
class MyApp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.r = redis.Redis()
    (all my app functions that touch redis go here)
```

I also don't want to pass the Redis pointer as an argument into every function.

Is there some other way I can get functions from different modules to share a single Redis() instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

Module `redis_manager`:

```
class RedisManager(object):
    def __init__():
        # Connect to redis etc
        self.redis = 12345


redis_manager = RedisManager()
```

Then in your other modules, you can do:

```
from redis_manager import redis_manager

redis_manager.redis.stuff
```

Comment: Oops, duh. Didn't think about making a file that *just* creates the connection and then importing the pointer rather than the class. Thanks!